# Sound localization with Kinect and ROS?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing a my senior project in school and want to do a robot that follows sound is it possible to access the Kinect's microphones for sound localization with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12279/sound-localization-with-kinect-and-ros?/) by [BC5389](https://answers.ros.org/users/1512/bc5389/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably check out the [HARK](http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/wiki.cgi?page=HARK-ROS-TURTLEBOT+Installation+Instructions) project.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3